# How to split a file while keeping punctuation AND whitespace?

Tags: regex, grep

I have an input file named `input.txt`. Its content:

> Sometimes, Perl's getting on my nerves

When I call `grep -Eo '\w+|[^\w ]' input.txt`, I get this output:

```
Sometimes
,
Perl
'
s
getting
on
my
nerves
!
```

However, I would like to keep each whitespace as well, meaning that I'd like to get this:

```
Sometimes
,

Perl
'
s

getting

on

my

nerves
!
```

How should I improve my `grep` to achieve what I want?

Comment: What has this to do with `perl`?

Comment: Since `[^\w]` matches a single non-word character, whitespace should be matched. As far as I can see, your "code" should work as it is. The problem lies elsewhere. How are you checking the output?

Comment: @ Jens: Woops, you're right... my bad... It's just that I'm working with perl on another stuff at the same time

@ TPL: It was actually  `[^\w ]` instead of `[^\w]`, resulting in my problem. When removing it, the whole thing works just fine. Thanks !